# Does using React context API force entire app to render on client in NextJS 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, rendering

In NextJS 13, I know that providers such as those used with the React context API can only be rendered in client components. I also know that the components within a client component (either child components or imported components) will be "considered part of the client bundle.", which I assume means they will be rendered on the client?

In the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#using-context-providers) it says that to use context providers you should create a client component that renders your provider and takes the components that need to access the provider as children e.g.

```js
'use client'
 
import { createContext } from 'react'
 
export const ThemeContext = createContext({})
 
export default function ThemeProvider({ children }) {
  return <ThemeContext.Provider value="dark">{children}</ThemeContext.Provider>
}
```

If you do this, does it not mean that everything with access to the provider will be rendered on the client, negating the majority of the performance benefit that NextJS offers from server side rendering? The docs show an example usage of the above code with a note:

```js
import ThemeProvider from './theme-provider'
 
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <ThemeProvider>{children}</ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

> notice how ThemeProvider only wraps {children} instead of the entire <html> document. This makes it easier for Next.js to optimize the static parts of your Server Components.

What is the relevance of the ThemeProvider only wrapping {children} and not the entire document? How does this make it easier for Next.js to optimise the static parts of the server components? Isn't it unlikely/rare to have any components outside the theme provider but within the html/body tags? I'm struggling to understand whether these examples in the docs are good examples that are conducive to efficient rendering, or whether they are last resorts if you desperately need to use a certain api such as the context provider.

Answer (score 0):

The performance benefits of SSR come from being able to deliver a fully-rendered HTML page to the client on the initial load, rather than waiting for a bundle of JavaScript to download, parse, and execute before the user can interact with the page. Even if some components are rendered on the client, as long as the majority of the page is server-rendered and can be delivered quickly, you still get the benefits of SSR.

In a typical application, most of your components will likely be inside some kind of provider, like a ThemeProvider or a Redux StoreProvider. But that doesn't mean they all have to be client-rendered. **You can have server components inside a provider, as long as they don't directly use the context**.